# Exiting prematurelly a FOR from an internal IF

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've been browsing a while but I haven't found a successful answer for this.. shouldn't be much trouble for an experienced SQL coder:

I have the following FOR loop with an IF condition inside, and I want to exit the loop whenever the IF condition is met

```
<<OUTER_LOOP>>
FOR I IN T_TITLE.FIRST.. T_TABLE.LAST LOOP
  IF T_TABLE(I).VAR_TITLE = PAR_TITLE THEN
    V_TITLE_ID = I;
    --insert exit here
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

I'm uncertain whether to use EXIT; EXIT OUTER_LOOP; or something like EXIT OUTER_LOOP WHEN V_TITLE_ID IS NOT NULL;

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `EXIT`:

```
FOR I IN T_TITLE.FIRST.. T_TABLE.LAST LOOP
  IF T_TABLE(I).VAR_TITLE = PAR_TITLE THEN
    V_TITLE_ID = I;
    EXIT;
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

You shouldn't use `EXIT WHEN` in this situation, because you wouldn't be able to save the value of `I`.

You could use `EXIT some_loop_label`, but it is not necessary in your situation. It may come in handy when you have nested loops, though.

More information here: [EXIT in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/exit_statement.htm)